# How to remove Tabs feature

Tags: ionic-framework

I've started my app using `ionic start myApp tabs`.

Now, I'd like to **totally** remove tabs from the app.

I tried changing startpage but it doesn't work...

Is there some kind of feature like `ionic generate remove...` ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't automatically remove pages with ionic CLI,
However, you can start a blank project with

```
ionic start myApp2 blank
```